# Request.url.absoluteuri not working asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the url of my current webpage.

I am using asp.net with MVC.

When I debug the code,see below, currentUri value is https://localhost:44377/. Should really be https://www.google.ca/. Please help.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://www.google.ca/", true);
        string currentUri = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

        return View();
    }
 }
```

Comment: It shouldn.t be `https://www.google.ca/`, because the request actually still the one on `localhost` until your browser redirect to google. And once it redirected, you still cannot get the request `AbsoluteUri` because it is out of your control then. So you cannot get the `AbsoluteUri` of the external URL you will redirect to. You should find another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Url` is url of the current request as server itself sees it. It is not necessary url that user used in they browser to look at the page (most sites have one or more "proxy" layers between server and user) and it definitely not a url of that will be set on *response* to be rendered as destination of 30x redirect.

If you are debugging locally the `Request.Url` is pretty much guaranteed to be `localhost`. Using IIS + hosts file you can assign local DNS name, but that still will be url of *request* and it can't be changed by code of the server (only configuration how server is actually receiving urls).

Answer (score 0):

The url returned belongs to the location from which the function HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri  is being called. In this case is from the  Index()  located at your  HomeController which is running in your local machine https://localhost:44377/.  The website https://www.google.ca/ is another website which your code doesn't have access to.